# mod_rewrite $10 value limitations, how to overcome this?

Tags: mod-rewrite

I've got a ReWrite rule that has more than 10 values. I know that the mod rewrite is limited to 9, I have seen 1 or 2 solutions with RewriteCond but couldn't get this to work for me.

I generated my rewrite rule via a web generator because I don't fully understand how to write the rules correctly.

This is my rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)\.html$ /search_properties.php?search=$1&country=$2&search_home_type=$3&search_home_town=$4&search_home_area=$5&search_rent_sale=$6&price_min=$7&price_max=$8&bedrooms=$9&bathrooms=$10&furnished=$11&search_agent=$12&order_by=$13 [L]
```

Any idea how I can overcome the $10 limit? Any help or tips are very welcome!

Thanks!

Comment: Pretty URLs for incredibly specific searches like this are a) unnecessary and b) obnoxious when they wind up indexed in search engines.

Answer (score 0):

You could split the rule into 2 rules. Something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*-[^-]*-[^-]*-[^-]*-[^-]*-[^-]*)\.html$ ineedmorevariables-$9?search=$1&country=$2&search_home_type=$3&search_home_town=$4&search_home_area=$5&search_rent_sale=$6&price_min=$7&price_max=$8
RewriteRule ^ineedmorevariables-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*) search_properties.php?bedrooms=$1&bathrooms=$2&furnished=$3&search_agent=$4&order_by=$5&somethingelse=$6 [L,QSA]
```

I haven't tested it though. All those parentheses are making me crazy.

PS. I see that the last parameter (`$14`) is never used.